# [Edited/include]man: bash. \e and bash shell "enter" token

Tags: bash, scripts

This is kind of a 2 part question and you'll understand why when done reading. To start, I was trying to figure how to cause an "enter" action inputted into standard *output* so that the script can inject a password into standard *input* (yes, I'm aware there are ssh-keys. It's more for the challenge of doing it). First, how do you do an "enter" in a bash script? I feel like \n is different in a small way. And, what does \e do. It's not documented in man bash.

To help clarify, I'm attempting to perform an "enter" functionality that would start an openssh-client connection.

> `#!/bin/bash`
>
> ssh miphix@foo.bar [*options*] [***interpreted enter command/token***]
>   
>   && sleep 5s
>   && echo "supersecretpassword" [***interpreted enter command/token***]

quickly followed by what other dreamy piles of fairy dust i can come up with.

Comment: You don't "input" into STDOUT (it's standard *output*), so what do you mean exactly? And what are you trying to do more specifically? `\e` introduces a generic escape sequence which is interpreted by the terminal and not by the shell.

Comment: I think maybe you need to use a semicolon `;` just a guess.

Comment: mchid it appears that there is no definition in man for ';' as a reserved function. Is this a SHell reservation for "sudo" scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo -ne '\n' | <command>
```

or just literally send to take advantage of implicit newline of echo:

```
echo | <command>
```

Comment: I think you're trying to say <command> | echo

Comment: No, I mean `echo | <command>`

Comment: Ok, not to be combative or inflammatory. Would you be so kind as to either expand on the logic, or link to an example?

>echo "secretpassword" | ssh miphix@foo.bar